# How to get the all month and year between two dates

Tags: date, go

How to get the all month and years for between two dates?

**Input**

```
From date: 2020-04-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
To date: 2021-03-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

**I need**

```
["April 2020", "May 2020", "June 2020".... "March 2021"]
```

Comment: What have you already tried? what problem did you face? Please read this before asking a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
start := "2020-04-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"
end := "2021-03-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC"

inLayout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
outLayout := "January 2006"
s, _ := time.Parse(inLayout, start)
e, _ := time.Parse(inLayout, end)
for e.After(s){
    fmt.Println(s.Format(outLayout))
    s = s.AddDate(0, 1, 0)
}
```

This will output:

```
April 2020
May 2020
June 2020
July 2020
August 2020
September 2020
October 2020
November 2020
December 2020
January 2021
February 2021
March 2021
```

[Here the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tzL04cHbgbb)

Some references about how to handle dates in Go:

- [Format a time or date [complete guide]](https://yourbasic.org/golang/format-parse-string-time-date-example/)
- [Add N number of Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute..](https://www.golangprograms.com/add-n-number-of-year-month-day-hour-minute-second-millisecond-microsecond-and-nanosecond-to-current-date-time.html)

Comment: It is ok; but answering such question leads people to think its ok to ask others to write code here and they do no research and try anything

Comment: It's a good answer, but it shouldn't exist. Don't feed the [help vampires](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava you're right  "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for life". I will ask for the real problem next time I found a question like this

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy ! I discover a new category :) you're right, is not a constructive behaviour